# Where is the mistake in the following?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

We know that *i =√(-1)*.

Now,
 **1/i = 1/ √(-1)
       = √ (1/(-1))
       =√(-1)
       =i**

Comment: Keep in mind, that $\sqrt{-1} = \pm i$

Comment: When √(x/y) = √(x) / √(y)?

Comment: @kingW3 Thank You..!!!